# ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycaret

While I running this command on command prompt

```
pip install pycaret
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-learn which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I already tried

```
pip install pep517
```

and

```
pip install p5py
```

and

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

/./....

and scikit-learn is already installed well..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HM3j.png)

help me plz...

+++++
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhNbT.png)

Comment: Please show the entire output of `pip install pycaret`, not just the error.

Comment: too long sir.. 
It goes well, but from here, a red message is displayed for a very long time, and at the end, an error message similar to the main text is output.

Comment: Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Building wheel for scikit-learn (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: i added picture in main text!

Comment: Could VSCode Bulid Tools be a problem too?

Comment: If you are using anaconda, you probably should be using the conda tools to install packages. It looks like for some reason your configuration is trying to compile some version of scikit-learn from scratch instead of using wheels.

Comment: thanks sir.. It was solved through virtual environment setting.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and found out that pycaret official release is not compatible with Python +3.9, found out there's this alpha version which doesn't have that problem:

pip install pycaret-ts-alpha

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while installing NumPy, Issue was resolved by upgrading Pip

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```